# update data and show in single page without page reloading using php

Tags: php

My first page is owner details then I send `id` and show owner wise driver in driver details page if I select particular driver and  show information in third page for select driver. In this page selected driver information show currently but when I perform update query so data not updated what I do. My problem is that show and update in same page and how to pass id of select item

```
<?php
include("config.php");
$d_idd            = $_GET['d_id'];
$_SESSION['d_id'] = $d_idd;
$d_id             = $_SESSION['d_id'];

//print_r("select * from tbl_multiple_driver where Id = '$d_id'");
die();

$driverUpdate = sqlsrv_query($conn,"select * from tbl_multiple_driver where Id = '$d_id'");

while($driverdetails = sqlsrv_fetch_array($driverUpdate)){
    $id         = $driverdetails['Id'];
    $name       =  $driverdetails['driver_name'];
    $mobile     =  $driverdetails['driver_mobile'];
    $dob        =  $driverdetails['driver_birth_date'];
    $address    =  $driverdetails['driver_address'];
    $location   =  $driverdetails['location'];
    $city       =  $driverdetails['city'];
    $pincode    =  $driverdetails['driver_pincode'];
    $pick_up_area       =  $driverdetails['PickUp_Area'];
    $vehicle_no         =  $driverdetails['vehicle_reg_no'];
    $vehicle_company    =  $driverdetails['V_id'];
    $vehicle_module     =  $driverdetails['V_id'];
    $user_name  =  $driverdetails['username'];
    $reg_date   =  $driverdetails['reg_date'];

    $vehicle = "SELECT * FROM Vehicle where id = '$vehicle_company'";
    $vehicleDisplay   = sqlsrv_query($conn,$vehicle);
    while($vehicleDetails = sqlsrv_fetch_array($vehicleDisplay)){
        $vehicleModel = $vehicleDetails['Vehicle_Model_id'];
    }

    $vehicleMod = "SELECT * FROM Vehicle_Modle where id = '$vehicleModel'";
    $vehicleModDisplay   = sqlsrv_query($conn,$vehicleMod);

    while($vehicleModDetails = sqlsrv_fetch_array($vehicleModDisplay)){
        $vehicleId = $vehicleModDetails['vehicle_id'];
        $vehicleModName = $vehicleModDetails['vehicle_modle_Name'];
    }

    $Mainvehicle = "SELECT * FROM MainVehicle where id = '$vehicleId'";
    $mainvehicleDisplay   = sqlsrv_query($conn,$Mainvehicle);

    while($mainvehicleDetails = sqlsrv_fetch_array($mainvehicleDisplay)){
        $vehiclename = $mainvehicleDetails['vehicle_company'];
    }   
}
?> 


<?php
if(isset($_POST['btnUpdate'])){ 
    //$id       = $_POST['Id'];
    $dName      = $_POST['txtDriverName'];
    $dMobile    = $_POST['txtMobileNumber'];
    $dDob       = $_POST['txtDob'];
    $dAddress   = $_POST['txtDriverAddress'];
    $dLocation  = $_POST['Location'];
    $dCity      = $_POST['city'];
    $dPincode   = $_POST['pincode'];
    $dPickUp    = $_POST['txtPickup'];
    $dVehicleNo = $_POST['txtVehicleNo'];

    //print_r("update tbl_multiple_driver set driver_name = '$dName',driver_mobile='$dMobile',driver_birth_date='$dDob',driver_address='$dAddress',location='$dLocation', city='$dCity',driver_pincode='$dPincode',PickUp_Area='$dPickUp', vehicle_reg_no='$dVehicleNo' where Id= '$id' ");  die();

    $driver_update = "update tbl_multiple_driver set driver_name = '$dName',driver_mobile='$dMobile',driver_birth_date='$dDob',driver_address='$dAddress',location='$dLocation', city='$dCity',driver_pincode='$dPincode',PickUp_Area='$dPickUp', vehicle_reg_no='$dVehicleNo' where Id= '$id' ";

    $res = sqlsrv_query($conn,$driver_update);
    if($res){
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href = Details.php';
        echo '</script>';
    }

    // header('location:Details.php');  
}
?>
```

Comment: Use `$_SESSION`. PS: there are a number of punctuation marks in English to make a text more readable.

Comment: Missing session_start()

Answer (score 0):

On user select you have to pass id again and then update info on base of this id:

```
$driver_update = "update tbl_multiple_driver set driver_name = '$dName',
driver_mobile='$dMobile',driver_birth_date='$dDob',‌​driver_address='$dAd‌​dress',
location='$dL‌​ocation', city='$dCity',driver_pincode='$dPincode',
PickUp_Area='$dPick‌​Up', vehicle_reg_no='$dVehicleNo' where Id='".$isession['d_id']."' ";
```

Comment: try this update query $driver_update = "update tbl_multiple_driver set driver_name = '$dName',driver_mobile='$dMobile',driver_birth_date='$dDob',driver_address='$dAddress',location='$dLocation', city='$dCity',driver_pincode='$dPincode',PickUp_Area='$dPickUp', vehicle_reg_no='$dVehicleNo' where Id= '".$isession['d_id']."' ";